# Development Board Choice

Tags: microcontroller, raspberry-pi, home-automation

I've been working with the [ATmega328](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8161.pdf) microcontroller for some time, with great success, but recently my projects have gone beyond the edge of its capabilities. I thought of switching to [ATmega2560](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2549.pdf) but held that thought and went further.

I've acquired a Raspberry PI board, and it's great but I really don't need a full computer here.

What I need is a development board with plenty of I/O, ADC, and PWM pins, support for multiple UART modules, I2C, SPI and CAN communication, fast enough to mess with video, network, and a community support on the web.

Feel free to give any opinions, my area is home automation aka domotics.

Comment: You might want to see the Makezine review of Arduino, Raspberry PI, and BeagleBoard [here](http://makezine.com/2013/04/15/arduino-uno-vs-beaglebone-vs-raspberry-pi/).

Comment: Because your question is primarily opinion-based, it's likely to be closed. That said, I'll offer one suggestion: Take a look at the [Atmel ARM-based microcontrollers](http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/arm/). You might find that a reasonable step up from the AVR's.

Comment: Well then I'd like to hear opinions from experts, I was quite specific, I just want names, a list, so I can search about, and if not too much, a healthy discussion over the subject. But since it's the rules, I'll be on my way :)

Comment: That's sort of the good/bad of SE, questions soliciting "lists" or opinions tend to not work out so well, because there's no way that a group of experts can agree on a "right" answer. If you rephrase the question a bit, you might be able to get one or two definitive boards that meet certain criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest the RasPi is probably your best bet. Even if it is a little overkill the price is hard to beat. Other boards you may want to take a look at:

The Chumby Hacking Board,
Beagle Boards by TI,
Mbed by NXP

Or read through this article that discusses several interesting alternatives to RasPi:

http://hackaday.com/2011/02/14/what-development-board-to-use-part-two/

Comment: Excellent article, I must say I'm quite interested in the Teensy 3.0 board!